# Выбор компилятора C++ в Windows

Tags: c++, windows, компилятор

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, компилятор C++ для Windows, чтобы его можно было использовать в таких программах как CLion, CodeBlocks и Geany.

Раньше использовал mingw, но он, вроде, больше не поддерживается.

Компилятор встроенный в Visual Studio вроде бы (?) нельзя использовать в Geany, поэтому Visual Studio не подходит.

Comment: Возьмите Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Comment: @Harry спасибо за совет, но, к сожалению, в силу некоторых причин Visual Studio не подходит

Comment: Поставьте MSYS 2, там есть и mingw и clang.

Comment: Если вам нужен не _любой_ компилятор, огласите ваши требования.

Comment: @VladD нужен компилятор, который можно использовать в CLion, CodeBlocks и Geany. Visual Studio вроде нельзя в Geany использовать, поэтому Visual Studio не подходит

Comment: @user268670: А почему нельзя? Geany не поддерживает компиляторы командной строки?

Comment: @VladD, поддерживает, просто поиск по запросу `using msvc in geany` не выдает каких-нибудь инструкций, поэтому я подумал, что нельзя использовать

Comment: @user268670: Ну, это как раз ожидаемо. Те, кто используют компиляторы из пакета MSVC, обычно используют и IDE, соответственно Geany им обычно нужно. Но думаю, что настроить можно вполне.

Comment: Есть [сайт](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html), на котором MinGW регулярно обновляется. Попробуйте воспользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, MinGW постоянно обновляется и дорабатывается (ссылка - [здесь](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)). Это очень популярный компилятор, и я не понимаю причин его менять на что-либо. Если кто-то и думает, что MinGW - это буковки и циферки, прыгающие в консоли, то он сильно ошибается. К тому же что еще можно предложить для обучения?

Во-вторых, при установке Code::Blocks предлагается выбор компилятора. Это значит, что Вы можете выбрать и MinGW, и любую версию Microsoft Visual C++, и любой другой компилятор.

Ну, а в-третьих, лучше всего для обучения подходит IDE под названием *Dev-C++*. Вряд ли в ближайшее время Вам потребуются такие первоклассные инструменты, как Clion)